# Get what's mine

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-request

I am going to say: "finally, I'll take what I think I should have in life (money,  power, etc.) from this life."

E.g. I'm talking to my friend and say:

I think I am not where I should be in life. I don't have what I think I should have had up to know. I think it is so unfair to be here in my life. But I'm confident I will take whatever that rightfully should belong to me from this life.

How should I say that in a natural way?

Once, an American friend told me I could say:

> - I will finally **get justice out** of this life.

But the problem is that I cannot find any reliable source which explains the idiom "get justice out"! This is why I think it is something made-up or it is simply wrong.

Also, I've encountered the excerpt below:

> I see the world through different eyes 
>   Took these dreams to make what's mine 
>   And we don't wait to take our time
>   Like I said, **I'll take what's mine** [[Source]](https://www.google.com/amp/s/genius.com/amp/Abstract-whats-mine-lyrics)

Then please kindly let me know if I can say:

> - **I'll finally take what's mine from this life.** (I think this is a natural way to say that; if you see nothing wrong with this quote, then I have my answer. If you don't, then please let me know what's wrong with it.)

I am wide open to any suggestions.

Comment: Sounds very dramatic - like what a villain or a very conceitedor perhaps very frustrated person may say, but I think it fits the dialog you have very well.  "I'll finally take what's mine from this life" - sounds good to my native ear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last thought `I'll finally take what's mine from this life` is a meaningful sentence. I don't see it as very natural, with apologies for disagreeing with Michael Dorgan's otherwise quite helpful comment.

He mentioned that your proposed sentence is dramatic, like from some villain, and I agree. It's also whiny, as though the speaker is a victim and is making sure to point out how unjust life has been till now. It might even be taken as a sort of rebellious response to difficult circumstances, as in `you can't defeat me!` while shaking your fist at fate, or destiny, or life, or who knows what.

Back to your sentence, and taking it in parts.

The `this` (in `this life`) is something you could leave out. `Get` works for `take.` `Finally` is not critical either, though it doesn't hurt (it is the primary word that makes the sentence whiny - which you may want). You could even put `what I deserve` in the place of `what's mine.`

One more: you could substitute `out of` for `from.` To me, `out of` sounds substantially more natural. Yes, you can get or take things *from* `life.` Taking makes more sense to me when the taking is from a being or group - identifiable agents, rather than some sort of impersonal collective term (`life`).

All of those possible options can be crafted into many more forms of your sentence. I'll list a few. I am not saying these are the best.

- I'll finally get what I deserve out of life.
- I'll take what I want from life.
- I'll make sure I get all I want out of life.
- I'll take what's mine from life.

The last three are the more direct and aggressive, which retains greater similarity to your suggested sentence. They also omit the whininess or victimhood.

Answer (score 1):

First, about the options you brought up:

- “get justice out of this life“ This makes it sound like someone’s wronged you and you’re trying to get revenge (ie it’s unclear what you’re saying) so I don’t think it’s a good option
- “take what's mine” This sounds at best arrogant/entitled and at worst a cliché line that you stole from a villain. Not a particularly good option either.

Considering this, I would suggest that you say that you finally hope to **get what you’ve worked for**. You can vary this a little and say that you’ve “worked so long and hard”, for emphasis.

What counts as working towards something? Well, you can use it in pretty much any circumstance where you’re not sitting around hoping something [falls into your lap](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+into+your+lap).

I’ve said it on multiple occasions about anything ranging from getting a good job (after spending the vast majority of my life in school working towards this, as kids do) to getting an achievement in a game after playing it for several hours. It’s pretty flexible as all things are relative, I guess.

Here is a [similar example in a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ht98DHdeM3cC&pg=PT8&lpg=PT8&dq=%22get%20what%20you%27ve%20worked%20for%22%20meaning&source=bl&ots=DvvlMAnIQc&sig=ACfU3U1hxuaR6eBZRwolBUbRb1WNUUKXHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP-9W1uazpAhWiY98KHZ0MCBUQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ):

> It will help you to get what you've worked for and deserve.